# Git add branch starting from N commits before latest commit

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working on `master` branch, lets I've made like `10 000 commits`, and what if I want to remove all the commits starting from `9876-th commit` and place them into **separate** `branch` (of course branch should include my `master` branch commits already done before making this new branch)?

P.S. The commit count isn't real, I'm just asking what should I do if it'd be an actual commit count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the start of the commit hash of the 9876th commit, you can checkout that individual commit. For example:

`git checkout 8f3faf -b branch_name`

Or if you know how many commits you want to *go back* you can branch from HEAD.
Using your example you'd want to go back 124 commits

`git checkout HEAD~124 -b branch_name`

In this particular scenario, we want all the current commits on *master* to be in a *separate* branch. Then we want to roll back master N-commits.

On master:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
git checkout -
git reset --hard HEAD~N
```

Now **master** will be reset back N commits, and the new branch **branch_name** will have those N commits ahead of **master**.

As an aside: The `git checkout -` is a shorthand to checkout out the last branch (in this case the **master** branch) you were on (similar to the `cd -` command which does the same thing but with directories on the filesystem).

Comment: Actually, I could make new branch, revert changes on master back to N-th commit, and new branch will have all the commits after N-th commit and all those were commited before N-th.

Comment: @PāvelsSanatovs Yes absolutely. I've done the same thing before where I've started committing on the wrong branch, then checkout a new branch and roll master back. I'll update the answer so that it actually answers the question fully ;)